# How to format JSON file in Vim

Tags: formatting, filetype-json

Given a file with a large JSON object all on one line like

```
{"versions":[{"count":2,"version":""},{"count":1,"version":"1.1.1"},{"count":14,"version":"2.9"},{...
```

How can I format this to be human readable in Vim?

Comment: Related StackOverflow Post: [How to fix JSON indentation in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16620835/438329)

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Or you can install `jq` which is faster (written in C) from your package manager (e.g. `sudo apt install jq` in Ubuntu/Debian, `sudo dnf install jq` on Fedora/RHEL/CentOS) or [from source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) and then in vim, type:

```
:%!jq .
```

Comment: `:%!jq` works just as well for me.

Comment: Hm... only works with the added `.` for me. I wonder why.

Comment: on MacOS, I need the ```.``` as well

Comment: Don't need to install `jq` on Ubuntu/Debian 14+ onward.

Comment: On MacOS after installing jq with `brew install jq` I could also just type `:%!jq` without a dot at the end

Comment: Sometimes, when I search for how to do something inside vim, I find theses answers that reminds me that one of the reasons I love vim is because it works seamlessly with all command line tools we already have.

Comment: @logbasex I have to on Ubuntu 20

Comment: i have malformed json file unfortunately and seems running the above command just puts the error output from jq into the current buffer.

Comment: Would love to see an explanation on the syntax of this command (well, I do know `jq` as a command line tool) and how it's being used by vim in this particular case.

Comment: @Alexandre `%` stands for a range equal to `1,$` (the entire file) and `!` filters the range of line to the external program `jq`.

Comment: For those stuck on Windows, you can install `jq` as a [chocolatey package](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/jq)

Comment: @Thomas, @logbasex, @RémyHosseinkhanBoucher, the `.` is the identity filter, meaning "give me back exactly what I gave you." Without a filter, some versions or invocations of `jq` will not assume which part of the JSON you want it to process, so it's best to always include the dot. See `man jq`. Use `:%!jq . --tab` to get indentation with tabs.

Answer (score 96):

This one-liner works well to format JSON in Vim into a human readable form:

`:%!python -m json.tool`

Comment: Do you memorize that and type it every time or do you use some kind of alias?

Comment: I tend to use the `:%!jq .` answer these days, as I do less with Python and tend to have `jq` installed on my systems for any JSON work in CLI. I also get notifications for this SO question quite often, so it helps me not to forget :P I prefer vim with minimal customization, no plugins, etc, which is another reason the `jq` solution is now my preferred.

Comment: (updated accepted answer to reflect this)

Comment: Just a warning that this will escape some characters into ASCII only. So if you want UTF8 encoding jq is the better option.

Comment: [Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#cmdoption-json-tool-no-ensure-ascii) has introduced the option `--no-ensure-ascii`.

Comment: Useful if you are on a cloud environment and don't have permissions to install `jq`

Answer (score 11):

To format in a deterministic way, we need to sort the hash. None of the other answers did that for me, so I created my own:

```
function! FormatJson()
python << EOF
import vim
import json
try:
    buf = vim.current.buffer
    json_content = '\n'.join(buf[:])
    content = json.loads(json_content)
    sorted_content = json.dumps(content, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    buf[:] = sorted_content.split('\n')
except Exception, e:
    print e
EOF
endfunction
```

Usage:

```
:call FormatJson()
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Nice first answer; it's interesting that you consider the sorting aspect!

Comment: About the sorting I'm pretty sure `jq` mentionned in SebMa answers has a `--sort-keys` option which would do the job. But it's cool to write your own implementation too :)

Answer (score 5):

I use this `:Jsonf` command. It's can format unicode.

```
command! Jsonf :execute '%!python -c "import json,sys,collections,re; sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r\"\\\u[0-9a-f]{4}\", lambda m:m.group().decode(\"unicode_escape\").encode(\"utf-8\"),json.dumps(json.load(sys.stdin, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict), indent=2)))"'
```

Answer (score 1):

If PHP is available, add the tool `jf` as a [JSON Formatter](https://whitephp.net/2018/07/31/jf-cli-json-formatter.html) by Composer:

```
$ composer global require codegear/json-formatter
```

Then Format current file:

```
:%!jf %
```

Or add a keymap in vimrc:

```
nnoremap <Leader>jf :%!jf %<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `nodejs` and `xargs` are available on your system you can add the following command to your `.vimrc`

```
command! -range FormatJson <line1>,<line2>!xargs -0 -I {} node -e 'console.log(JSON.stringify({}, null, 2));'
```

After that you can visual select the JSON text in the buffer and run

```
:'<,'>FormatJson
```

to pretty print it. Works with Unicode too.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [coc-format-json](https://github.com/gera2ld/coc-format-json).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This answer would benefit from further explanation via [edit].

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to open jq with vim. However i didn't manage to find a way to do it in one command.

I wrote a shell script, and it worked for me (linux version : redhat 7.6):

```
# Don't miss the dot after jq
cat input.json | jq . > output.json
vim output.json
```

Comment: You can use `-` to read from stdin: `jq input.json . | vim -` (maybe you need to reverse the `input.json` and `.` in that `jq` command). Another option would be to use `-c` or `+` to run a command when Vim opens: `vim +':%!jq .' input.json`

Answer (score 0):

**Use ALE to help you with linting/formatting**

1. Install [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale.git) into **.vim/vimfiles/pack/*/opt/ale**
2. add the following line to your vimrc:

```
packadd ale
```

3. create **.vim/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/json.vim**

```
if exists("b:my_ftplugin") | finish | endif
let b:my_ftplugin = 1
if !exists('g:loaded_ale') | finish | endif
" Pick from available fixers :help ale-fix
" E.g., use prettier if it is installed:
let b:ale_fixers = ['prettier']
```

If no fixers are available at your disposal, python is always an option:

```
if !executable('python') | finish | endif
let b:ale_fixers = [{ -> {'command': 'python -m json.tool --indent 2 -'}}]
```

4. Run the following command to reformat the current vim buffer:

```
:ALEFix
```

Answer (score 0):

### Only usable for one (or few) files.

Set all values at a new line with substitute commands (they must fit your file!):

- `:%s/","/",\r"/g`
- `:%s/null,"/null,\r"/g`
- `:%s/(\d),"/\1,\r"/g`
- ... (there are `},{`, `[{`

```
{
"versions":[
{
"count":2,"version":""
},
{"count":1,
"version":"1.1.1"
},
{
"count":14,
"version":"2.9"
}]
}
```

Then go to the first `{` and type <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>%</kbd>.

The JSON will be rudimentary formatted. Not perfect but readable.